# List permutation existance

Tags: c#, linq, list, listview

**i have a list**

```
 List<PossibleSolutionCapacitors> PossibleSolution = new List<PossibleSolutionCapacitors>();
```

**here is its class**

```
 class PossibleSolutionCapacitors
    {
        public int CapacitorALocation { get; set; }
        public int CapacitorBLocation { get; set; }
        public int CapacitorCLocation { get; set; }    
    }
```

**i have 3 integers**

```
 int A;
 int B;
 int C;
```

**i need to check if any combination of A,B,C is contained in the list possible solutions**

i.e if the following are in the list (Boolean saying true/false is enough)

1. A,B,C
2. A,C,B
3. B,A,C
4. etc...

**is this possible ?**

thanks
Damo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variation on Save's solution:

```
var fixedSet = new HashSet<int>(){A,B,C};
bool result = PossibleSolutions.Any(x => fixedSet.SetEquals(
    new[] { x.CapacitorALocation,x.CapacitorBLocation,x.CapacitorCLocation }));
```

Comment: is this solution faster than Save's ?

Comment: I have no idea if it's faster, but it's less complicated and easier to understand, that makes it, even if the running time is the same, better.

Comment: I have just run some stopwatch test, and the execution time is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = PossibleSolution.Any(x=>HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer()
               .Equals(new HashSet<int>(){A,B,C}
                   ,new HashSet<int>(){x.CapacitorALocation,x.CapacitorBLocation,x.CapacitorCLocation}));
```

To save some time, you can create the `HashSet<int>(){A,B,C}` and the comparer beforehand, and call it in your code, with something like:

```
var fixedSet = new HashSet<int>(){A,B,C};
IEqualityComparer<HashSet<int>> comparer = HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer();

var query = PossibleSolution.Any(
            x=>comparer.Equals(fixedSet,new HashSet<int>(){x.CapacitorALocation,x.CapacitorBLocation,x.CapacitorCLocation}));
```

And finally, for a version that uses `SetEquals` instead of the comparer, check Thomas Levesque solution.

Comment: +1, but you should probably create the set comparer outside the lambda, otherwise you will create it once for each possible solution

Comment: yea while you commented i was adding that version to the solution :) thanks for pointing out anyway

Comment: btw, I don't think you need CreateSetComparer; you could just use the SetEquals method

Comment: mmm ... I creted the comparer because I'm not sure wether or not SetEquals does a deep comparison. I'll look into it and eventually update