# see if any item exists in any list item

Tags: c#, linq, list, listview

**i have a list**

```
        List<FirstIterationCapacitors> FirstIteration = new List<FirstIterationCapacitors>(); // A set of Solution capacitors object
```

**Here is it's class**

```
class FirstIterationCapacitors
    {
        public int Iteration { get; set; }
        public int CapacitorALocation { get; set; }
        public int CapacitorBLocation { get; set; }
        public int CapacitorCLocation { get; set; }
    }
```

**Now i have a second list**

```
        List<PossibleSolutionCapacitors> PossibleSolution = new List<PossibleSolutionCapacitors>(); // Possible Solution capacitors object
```

**here is its class**

```
 class PossibleSolutionCapacitors
    {
        public int CapacitorALocation { get; set; }
        public int CapacitorBLocation { get; set; }
        public int CapacitorCLocation { get; set; }      

    }
```

For a given row (i.e for row 2) in PossibleSolution i need to see if

1. PossibleSolution.CapacitorALocation does not exist in
   FirstIteration.CapacitorALocation (that equal to iteration X) or
   FirstIteration.CapacitorBLocation (that equal to iteration X) or
   FirstIteration.CapacitorCLocation (that equal to iteration X)

OR

1. PossibleSolution.CapacitorBLocation does not exist in
   FirstIteration.CapacitorALocation (that equal to iteration X) or
   FirstIteration.CapacitorBLocation (that equal to iteration X) or
   FirstIteration.CapacitorCLocation (that equal to iteration X)

OR

1. PossibleSolution.CapacitorCLocation does not exist in
   FirstIteration.CapacitorALocation (that equal to iteration X) or
   FirstIteration.CapacitorBLocation (that equal to iteration X) or
   FirstIteration.CapacitorCLocation (that equal to iteration X)

ideally a boolean stating true false if the condition is true/false

**Here is what i have tried so far but it is not working**

```
int D = 4; // The row i care about

int E = PossibleSolution[D].CapacitorALocation;
int F = PossibleSolution[D].CapacitorBLocation;
int G = PossibleSolution[D].CapacitorCLocation;



var fixedSet = new HashSet<int>() {E};
if (!FirstIteration.Any(x => fixedSet.SetEquals(new[] { x.CapacitorALocation, x.CapacitorBLocation, x.CapacitorCLocation })))
{
fixedSet = new HashSet<int>() {F};
if (!FirstIteration.Any(x => fixedSet.SetEquals(new[] { x.CapacitorALocation, x.CapacitorBLocation, x.CapacitorCLocation })))
{

fixedSet = new HashSet<int>() {G};
if (!FirstIteration.Any(x => fixedSet.SetEquals(new[] { x.CapacitorALocation, x.CapacitorBLocation, x.CapacitorCLocation })))
{

//Match does not exist so do some real work here ......

}

}

}
```

thanks,
damo

Comment: What does the SetEquals do?

Comment: see this solution last night to a similar problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601502/list-permutation-existance

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis Returns true if the two sets have the same items, and false if they don't.  Think of it as a `SequenceEquals` that doesn't require the items to be in the same order.

Comment: The problem is, you wrote that your two elements are list, but in the 3 test you refer to them as if they are just an instance of PossibleSolutionCapacitors . Do you want to compare the two lists index per index or what? Yesterdays' problem was quite different since you just had to compare a List to a single set of items ... today you are showing 2 lists and no correlation between them

Comment: got it Save - See dasblinkenlight's answer below - thanks damo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in all three of your conditions you check if a particular location

> does not exist in `FirstIteration.CapacitorALocation` or `FirstIteration.CapacitorBLocation` or `FirstIteration.CapacitorCLocation`

you can collect all these locations in a single `Set<int>` for a quick check:

```
var firstIterationLocations = new HashSet<int>(
    firstIterationCapacitorList
    .Where(loc => loc.Iteration == X)
    .SelectMany(
        loc => new[] {loc.CapacitorALocation, loc.CapacitorBLocation, loc.CapacitorCLocation}
    )
);
```

With `firstIterationLocations` in hand, you can build your condition as follows:

```
if (!(firstIterationLocations.Contains(PossibleSolution[D].CapacitorALocation)
||    firstIterationLocations.Contains(PossibleSolution[D].CapacitorBLocation)
||    firstIterationLocations.Contains(PossibleSolution[D].CapacitorCLocation))
) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: this isnt working - are you sure that var firstiter... is correct - it returns an array of some sort but not a trio listing of each capacitorlocation - also should each OR statement have an ! in front of the word First ?

Comment: @user1438082 It's adding all locations to a single set, because all your checks verify that a location `A`, `B`, or `C` is not among any of the locations from the first iteration; that's why I put them all in a single set. As far as the `!` goes, it's in front of a parenthesized expression, not in front of the first item, so there should be only one.

Comment: it is working i think - one minor change - i only want var firstIterationLocations to use loc.CapacitorALocation , loc.CapacitorBLocation, loc.CapacitorCLocation where Iteration = X (See class FirstIterationCapacitors for its definition) i will also update the question.

Comment: @user1438082 This translates into LINQ almost literally - with an added `Where()` clause.

Answer (score -1):

So what you want to know is if any of the items in the first set of locations are in the second set of locations.  You can think of that as asking if the intersection of the two sets has any items:

```
public static bool Match(FirstIterationCapacitors first
    , FirstIterationCapacitors second)
{
    return new[]{
        first.CapacitorALocation,
        first.CapacitorBLocation,
        first.CapacitorCLocation
        }.Intersect(new[]{
            second.CapacitorALocation,
            second.CapacitorBLocation,
            second.CapacitorCLocation,
        })
        .Any();
}
```

Comment: Is he looking for the intersection or the difference?  If its difference than you can interchange the Intersect method with the Except method

Comment: @BrettSanderson The intersection.  He wants to know if any items in the first set are in the second.  If it was a set difference that would be asking, "Are all of the items in the first set in the second?" which doesn't appear to be what he wants based on the question.

Comment: He wants if any item in A does not exist in B it seems from what he said.  I dunno, this is easy solution to mess around with anyway so I up voted it.

Comment: Does int A or Int B or Int C exist in any Row of the list in any combination. Just compare 3 ints to the list - not a list within a list

Comment: @user1438082 Your requirements weren't to compare the three values to all of the values in all of the items in the entire list.  Your requirements were to compare two `FirstIterationCapacitors` objects.  Putting all three properties into a list was simply the easiest way to do it.  That said, if you *want* to compare it to all of the values throughout all of the items in all of the lists, you can put them all into the collection that you intersect with through a simple `SelectMany` call, as is done in the other answer.